# An interesting Restlet Attribute behavior

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

Using Restlet 2.1 for Java EE, I am discovering an interesting problem with its ability to handle attributes.

Suppose you have code like the following:

```
cmp.getDefaultHost().attach("/testpath/{attr}",SomeServerResource.class);
```

and on your browser you provide the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8100/testpath/command
```

then, of course, the attr attribute gets set to "command".

Unfortunately, suppose you want the attribute to be something like command/test, as in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8100/testpath/command/test
```

or if you want to dynamically add things with different levels, like:

```
http://localhost:800/testpath/command/test/subsystems/network/security
```

in both cases the attr attribute is still set to "command"!

Is there some way in a restlet application to make an attribute that can retain the "slash", so that one can, for example, make the attr attribute be set to "command/test"? I would like to be able to just grab everything after testpath and have the entire string be the attribute.

Is this possible? Someone please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same case I usually change the type of the variable :

```
Route route = cmp.getDefaultHost().attach("/testpath/{attr}",SomeServerResource.class);
route.getTemplate().getVariables().get("attr") = new Variable(Variable.TYPE_URI_PATH);
```

Comment: Though both solutions work, I like yours better because I'd hate to use the former in situations where users might have to enter a URL. Both solutions are good, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using url encoding.

I made the following attachment in my router:

```
router.attach("/test/{cmd}", TestResource.class);
```

My test resource class looks like this, with a little help from [Apache Commons Codec URLCodec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html)

```
@Override
protected Representation get() {
    try {
    String raw = ResourceWrapper.get(this, "cmd");
    String decoded = new String(URLCodec.decodeUrl(raw.getBytes()));
    return ResourceWrapper.wrap(raw + " " + decoded);
    } catch(Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

Note my resource wrapper class is simply utility methods. The get returns the string of the url param, and the wrap returns a StringRepresentation.

Now if I do something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/haha/awesome
```

I get a 404.

Instead, I do this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/haha%2fawesome
```

I have URLEncoded the folder path. This results in my browser saying:

```
haha%2fawesome haha/awesome
```

The first is the raw string, the second is the result. I don't know if this is suitable for your needs as it's a simplistic example, but as long as you URLEncode your attribute, you can decode it on the other end.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great solution for situations where the client application is generating the URL...

Comment: I think the idea of users entering their own urls for commands is a bad idea, personally. But if you got the problem solved, that's great!